# sql query LIKE % on Index

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a mysql database.
My website is cut in different elements (PRJ_12 for projet 12, TSK_14 for task 14, DOC_18 for document 18, etc). We currently store the references to these elements in our database as VARCHAR. The relation columns are Indexed so it is faster to select.

We are thinking of currint these columns in 2 columns (on column "element_type" with PRJ and one "element_id" with 12). We are thinking on this solution as we do a lot of requests containing LIKE ...% (for example retrieve all tasks of one user, no matter the id of the task).
However, splitting these columns in 2 will increase the number of Indexed columns.

So, I have two questions :

1. Is a `LIKE ...%` request in an Indexed column realy more slow than a a simple where query (without like). I know that if the column is not indexed, it is not advisable to do `where ... LIKE %` requests but I don't realy know how Index work).
2. The fact that we split the reference columns in two will double the number of Indexed table. Is that a problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Indexes are organised data structures. When you do a query such as `WHERE field_name LIKE 'term%'` (note that wildcard is at the end of the search term), then MySQL CAN use an index, given the fact field_name is indexed. It will be quick, depending on how many records you have and what resources the computer can provide. If MySQL uses indexes, it's generally much faster than checking the actual data due to organisational structure of the index.

Answer (score 1):

1) A like is always more costly than a full comparison (with = ), however it all comes down to the field data types and the number of records (unless we're talking of a huge table you shouldn't have issues)

2) Multicolumn indexes are not a problem, yes it makes the index bigger, but so what? Data types and ammount of total rows matter, but thats what indexes are for.

So go for it

Comment: So, considering my column is Indexed, is it much slower to make a LIKE  request in Index rather than a simple where? I wonder if it is worth it to change all my request to adapt to a new database structure or if the performance won't increase that much.

Comment: Direct index access is always faster. And if your like only uses one % and the end of the expression, the dmbs can do some very fast searches to get the values. The point is, with a standard where on an indexed column you'll only get one record, with a like you may get more. Thats a functional change on the query. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors involved, but in general, adding one more index on a table that has only one index already is unlikely to be a big problem.  Some things to consider.

- If the table most mostly read-only, then it is almost certainly not a problem.  If updates are rare, then the indexes won't need to be modified often meaning there will be very little extra cost (aside from the additional disk space).
- If updates to existing records do not change either of those key values, then no index modification should be needed and so again there would be no additional runtime cost.
- DELETES and INSERTS will need to update both indexes.  So if that is the majority of the operations (and far exceeding reads), then an additional index might incur measurable performance degradation (but it might not be a lot and not noticeable from a human perspective).
- The like operator as you describe the usage should be fully optimized.  In other words, the clause `WHERE combinedfield LIKE 'PRJ%'` should perform essentially the same as `WHERE element_type = 'PRJ'` if there is an index existing in both situations.  The more expensive situation is if you use the wild card at the beginning (e.g., `LIKE '%abc%'`).  You can think of a LIKE search as being equivalent to looking up a word in a dictionary.  The search for 'overf%' is basically the same as a search for 'overflow'.  You can do a "manual" binary search in the dictionary and quickly find the first word beginning with 'overf'.  Searching for '%low', though is much more expensive.  You have to scan the entire dictionary in order to find all the words that end with "low".
- Having two separate fields to represent two separate values is almost always better in the long run since you can construct more efficient queries, easily perform joins, etc.

So based on the given information, I would recommend splitting it into two fields and index both fields.